# MongoDB not creating database in shell

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a book to learn MongoDB. It says that in order to create a db in Mongo, I just need to 'use' it.

```
show dbs
admin 0.000GB
local 0.000GB
```

When I do, `use someDBName`

It says `switched to db someDBName`

But when I do `show dbs`

I just see admin and local again. I don't see the someDBName database.

Comment: It will not appear until it has some data. Try inserting something in it and you will see the db in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will not show until your database is empty.
To have your database shown you can use

`create collection` command to insert collection then it will be shown to you by using

```
show dbs
```

Answer (score 5):

Per the MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#databases):

If a database does not exist, MongoDB creates the database when you first store data for that database. As such, you can switch to a non-existent database and perform the following operation in the mongo shell:

```
use myNewDB
db.myNewCollection1.insertOne( { x: 1 } )
```

The `insertOne()` operation creates both the database `myNewDB` and the collection `myNewCollection1` if they do not already exist.