# Create new database with API call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create a new database at the time of the API call. I am already connected to one main database.

I have tried using mongoose.connect() method. And it gives me a positive response. But when I checked in mongo console I did not find the newly created database.

Here is my code.

```
const connectionString = `mongodb://${process.env.DB_HOST}:${
    process.env.DB_PORT
  }/client_${Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substring(2, 8)}`;

  mongoose.connect(
    connectionString,
    {
      autoReconnect: true,
      reconnectTries: 60,
      reconnectInterval: 10000,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Connected');
      }
    }
  );
```

Hope you got my point. Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mongodb documentation:

> If a database does not exist, MongoDB creates the database when you first store data for that database. As such, you can switch to a non-existent database and perform the following operation in the mongo shell. [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#databases)

This is true for mongo-shell as well, if you do `use mydb;` to create one and immediately do `show dbs;` it won't show up unless you create some data for that `mydb` like `createCollection(), insert() etc`.

So your code is alright because `connect()` is as good as `use db;`. Unless you create some data for that db you won't see that in mongo console.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any parameter which will create a default collection while creating new Database?

Comment: @rahul If you were using node-native driver it would have been pretty simple as `db.createCollection('collectionString', callback)`. But `mongoose` exposes the `createCollection()` on `Model` and does not create one unless you `save/create` one doc. Read more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100881/mongodb-not-creating-database-in-shell)

Comment: Thanks, let me try with this